# Sitecore media item downloads

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-dms

I need to get number of downloads per document in Media Library. I am using Sitecore 6.4.1 and Sitecore OMS 1.1.1. Is there a Sitecore built-in way or API that allow me to retrieve such information?

Answer (score 0):

Well you cannot make sure that the download has completed, but a hit is registered so you can go to the media item, click the analyze tab and then reports. As far as I remember you should now be able to select a report of hits.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that you need to make sure that the download is captured by OMS. You have to associate the download event with the item that is downloaded.  Once you do that, you can go to the download report and see the number of times it's been downloaded.  If you don't associate the download event with the item, however, it will not trigger the page event and therefore will not be trackable in OMS.